# How do I post on Battlenet forums using my Diablo 3 license?

Tags: battle.net

Long ago, I played ***the Warcraft***, and thus I had a Battlenet account. Much time passed, and now I have come back for Diablo 3 - but I can't seem to post on the forums.  I get the following error:

> REPLY TO THREAD
>
> This account has limited posting access due to the following condition:
> This game license has expired or been cancelled.

... but I have a brand new Diablo 3 license!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click your account character name (located below the search bar in the forums), it should have a down arrow next to it. Click "Manage Characters" and select your Diablo 3 game name and posting again.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked the forums, you needed to enter a specific key and select a few things for your first log on with a game.